# How to mock ActsAsTaggableOn with RSpec and Mocha?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, acts-as-taggable-on, ruby-mocha

How can i mock ActsAsTaggableOn::tag using RSpec and Mocha ? I'm new to rails testing so i might be missing something obvious...

I tried :

/spec/controllers/books_controller.rb

```
it "should return 2 categories whith books" do

      tag_ruby = mock_model(ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, :name => 'ruby', :context => 'category')
      tag_java = mock_model(ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, :name => 'java', :context => 'category')

      ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.stubs(:with_context).returns([tag_ruby, tag_java])

      get 'books_by_categories'
      assigns(:books_by_categories).should be_empty
end
```

/app/controllers/books_controller

```
  def books_by_categories
    @books_by_categories = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.with_context('category').all.map { |category|
      {:name => category.name, :books => category.books.visibles.limit(10)}
    }
  end
```

I get :

```
Failure/Error: tag_ruby = mock_model(ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, :name => 'ruby', :context => 'category')
     Mocha::ExpectationError:
       unexpected invocation: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.__mock_proxy()
       unsatisfied expectations:
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.id(any_parameters)
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.name(any_parameters)
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.marked_for_destruction?(any_parameters)
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.valid?(any_parameters)
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.persisted?(any_parameters)
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.context(any_parameters)
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.destroyed?(any_parameters)
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag_1001>.blank?(any_parameters)
```